# append a NSSet with array values

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode

How can i append my HKObjectTypes into a NSSet.
It always returns empty. Any better way???

```
     func getPermsFromOptions(_ options: NSArray) -> NSSet {
            var readPermSet = NSSet()
            var optionKey: String
            var val: HKObjectType
                
           for i in options{
            optionKey = i as! String
            val = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier(rawValue: optionKey))!

             readPermSet.adding(val)    
             print("set", readPermSet)           //always empty

                      }
                  return readPermSet;
              }
```

Comment: `var readPermSet = NSSet()` => `var readPermSet = NSMutabmeSet()` and then, `readPermSet.add(val)`, but why do you keep using `NSArray` and `NSSet`? Can't you use Swift `Set` and `Array` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
readPermSet.adding(val)
```

Adding isn't a mutating method, it returns a new set that has the other value added

Try it with:

```
var readPermSet: Set<HKObjectType> = []
```

and

```
readPermSet.insert(val)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add to an `NSSet`. You *can* add to an `NSMutableSet`:

```
var readPermSet = NSMutableSet()
...
readPermSet.add(val)
```

`adding` is a method from Swift, that *returns* a new set with all the same elements, plus the new element. You are ignoring its return value here.

Since you are in Swift, why not use `Set<HKObjectType>` and `[String]`?

```
func getPermsFromOptions(_ options: [String]) -> Set<HKObjectType> {
    var readPermSet = Set<HKObjectType>()
    for optionKey in options {
        let val = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier(rawValue: optionKey))!
         readPermSet.insert(val)    
         print("set", readPermSet)
     }
     return readPermSet;
 }
```